# Searching Large Directories for Multiple Folders - JAVA

Tags: java, search, directory, subdirectory

I want to be able to search a large directory, including all subfolders for **every** folder called "**online**" and add the folders once found to a list.

So in other words: Is this file a folder? if not ignore, if yes is this folder called "online"?, if yes add to list, if not open and cycle through folder contents and start again.

I have a script:

```
String fileType = "online";

private void buildList(File aFile) {
 if (aFile.isDirectory()) {

    if (fileName.contains(fileType)) {
        addToList(aFile);
    } else {
        for (File bFile : aFile.listFiles()) {
            buildList(bFile);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

This works fine on small directories but not on large directories due to the large number of arrays it has open. It hangs and uses up all the memory.

I'm open to all suggestions. JAVA only and ideally  JDK1.6 compatible. Thank you very much in advance!!!!

EDIT:

```
static long counter = 0L;
ArrayList<File> opFolders;


public final class DirectoryCollectorVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

   private final List<Path> list;



   public DirectoryCollectorVisitor(final List<Path> list) {


      this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(final Path path, final BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
        counterPrintField.setText("" + counter++);
        if (path.getFileName().toString().contains("online")) {
            list.add(path);
            File aFile = path.toFile();
            opFolders.add(aFile);
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}



private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    JFileChooser chooser = jFileChooser1;
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("O:\\Prod\\Clients"));
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == chooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            jTextArea1.setText(null);
            opFolders = new ArrayList<>();

            final Path baseDir = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
            final List<Path> dirList = new ArrayList<>();
            dirList.add(baseDir);

            final FileVisitor<Path> visitor = new DirectoryCollectorVisitor(dirList);
            Files.walkFileTree(baseDir, visitor);
            if(opFolders.isEmpty()){
                System.err.println("EMPTY");
            }
            for (File aFile : opFolders) {
                if (!aFile.isDirectory() && !aFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".db")) {
                    jTextArea1.append(aFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");

                }

            }

            jTextArea1.append("...COMPLETE...");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem accessing directory: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }

}
```

@fge updated code

Comment: Java 6 only? Too bad... Had you used Java 7+ there would have been a solution. With Java 6 you're pretty much SOL (no way to read directory entries lazily). But then this is 2015, so obligatory question: why Java 6? It's been years since it has reached its end of life

Comment: That's bizzare. Define `Large Directories`

Comment: @UmaKanth that's not bizarre at all; just imagine a directory hierarchy where each level has tens, or even hundreds, of thousands of files and you walk them recursively. As `File`'s `.listFiles()` returns an array, it has no choice but to eagerly populate the arrays, and this can quickly lead to huge memory consumption. Starting with JSR 203 and `DirectoryStream`, this is no longer a problem.

Comment: each recursion level creates a new file array. Still can't imagine a directory hierarchy which exhausts the memory when traversed in that way. Can you give some numbers (directory depth, average files per directory)?

Comment: Each folder may contain hundreds of other folders which may contain hundreds more and so on. I'm not stuck to using JDK1.6, though a JDK1.6 solution would be preferred for use on a seperate informatica project which only supports up to JDK1.6.

Comment: Why do you collect in a `List<File>` in addition to collecting the paths? This does not make sense

Comment: True missed that one, thanks @fge. It does work much faster now that is corrected. Now, is there a way using DirectoryCollectorVisitor, to ignore sub directories of "online"? EDIT: Ah, SKIP_SUBTREE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you say you are limited to Java 6. Given that requirement there is no way to use the `File` API to do that. `.listFiles()` can only populate directory entries in an eager fashion.

Well, there would be one way... Provided you use a Unix like operating system you could use a `ProcessBuilder` and issue a process from the base directory with a command such as `find -type d -name online`:

```
final File baseDir = ...;
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
    "find", "-type", "d", "-name", "online"
);
pb.directory(baseDir);

final Process p = pb.start();
// use the Process' InputStream
```

If you use Java 7+ you have an easier time; program a `FileVisitor` to collect into a list:

```
public final class DirectoryCollectorVisitor
    extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>
{
    private final List<Path> list;

    public DirectoryCollectorVisitor(final List<Path> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult previsitDirectory(final Path path, final BasicFileAttributes attrs)
    {
        if (path.getFileName().toString().equals("online"))
            list.add(path);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}

// ...

final Path baseDir = Paths.get(...);
final List<Path> dirList = new ArrayList<>();
final FileVisitor<Path> visitor = new DirectoryCollectorVisitor(list);
Files.walkFileTree(baseDir, visitor);
// dirList is not filled with the entries
```

With Java 8, it's even more simple:

```
private static final BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> ONLINE_DIRS 
    = (path, attrs) -> attrs.isDirectory() 
    && path.getFileName().toString().equals("online");

// ...

final Path baseDir = Paths.get(...);
final List<Path> dirList;

try (
    final Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(baseDir, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
        ONLINE_DIRS);
) {
    dirList = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Ok so the Java 7 solution works somewhat, but it is slow. Takes 1min to cycle through just 500 files. Any suggestions to improve this? Thank you!!!

Comment: @ldhxvs is that 500 files total or 500 results?

Comment: 534 folders total in 1 directory (2,326 files)

Comment: @ldhxvs What OS is that? 1 minute is clearly an abnormal time. Can you paste the code you use? Also, if you use Java 8, can you try the Java 8 solution to see whether it makes a difference?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional 64bit, SP1, Intel i5-4590 3.3GHz, 12GB ram.